# Rails 3 Rendering JS not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I am a huge beginner and I am learning and doing some practice work with rails 3 and RJS requests.
I am doing a RJS test with the following which I got from a tutorial.

The following is in my index.rhtml. In my header I have the tags I have noticed people post around such as teh javascript_include_tag and csrf_meta_tag

```
 <div id="rjs">I will be updated.</div>
```

The Following line is for sure incorrect. Which is probably my problem. I have seen different rails 2 implementations but I've read that in Rails 3 it has changed and can't seem to get it working. My Url is the problem. I can't set up my url statment correctly which is probably the problem.

```
 <%= link_to "Test out RJS!", rjs_path(@rjs), :remote => true %>
```

My hello.rjs file has the following

```
page.replace_html "rjs", "<b>See!</b>"
```

My controller is the following

```
class RjsController < ApplicationController
def hello
end
```

From the guide I was following this should switch the original "I will be updated" to "See" when you click the link but in my case nothing happens when I click the link
    end

Would someone be able to help me with my link_to line and possibly give me a explanation as too why it is written the way it is. Thank You

Comment: Are you using jQuery and jrails or Prototype? Do you have any JavaScript errors when executing that action?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `:respond_to` on top of your controller like this?

```
class RjsController < ApplicationController   
  respond_to :js

  def hello   
  end

end
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JQuery and JRails and checking in firefox it tells me JQuery is not defined. I thought I set everything up in my rails app correctly. Sorry I am new to the site. Also putting respond_to :js did not change anything

My error brings me to this line of my rails.js that i overwritten when adding the adapter for Unbotrusive scripting adapter for JQuery

```
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: This may be more a Ajax question but I am not quite sure as I am kind of new but firebug throws that JQuery Undefined Error

Comment: I fixed the JQuery Undefined error by adding <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.4' %> to my header of application.html.erb but now i get no errors and nothing happens